# export { default } from module does not work with Babel 7 and preset-env in Jest

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs, babel-loader, babel-jest

After migrating to Babel 7 when I launch my tests I get this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`

for this line (e.g. `index.js` file):

`export { default } from './SearchInput';`

Where `SearchInput.jsx` file is in the same folder and is using

`export class SearchInput {}`

syntax.

This happens only in Jest tests (in app runtime it works).

How can I fix it?

EDIT:

This is my babel config `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache.forever();
  return {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
  };
};
```

It seems that jest does not respect `plugins`, cos when I removed `static defaultProps` and `static propTypes` and moved them to `SearchInput.defaultProps` and `SearchInput.propTypes`, tests started to work.

Comment: The only way I could see this happening is if you have dependency cycles, so you're trying to import `SearchInput` before it is actually available. You'd need to make a reduced example of your file structure that demonstrates the folder structure in order to verify.

Comment: I've updated question with hint - it seems it has something to do with babel plugins

Comment: I have the same issue. My app seems to run fine but Jest test failing with "Cannot read property 'default' of undefined". Did you find a solution?

Comment: @dragonfly I am also facing the exact issue. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: In the end, it turned out that I had dependency cycle that was really hard to spot. Once I reorganized by files is started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to upgrade babel-jest as well.

> Note: If you are using babel version 7 you have to install babel-jest with
>
> ```
> yarn add --dev babel-jest 'babel-core@^7.0.0-bridge' @babel/core
> ```
>
> https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest

Comment: I have it all - most of the tests are passing. Failing ones are importing components that are exported using `index.js` files with `export { default } from 'sthsth;`

Comment: Same for me. Did you fixed this?

Comment: I assume `default` is a reserved word for the default export, which the neither the class file nor the index.js seems to have.